# React: How to send string to a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component:

```
import React from "react";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";

const GlobalMessage = function(props) {
  return (
    <Snackbar
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "center"
      }}
      open="{props.error}"
      autoHideDuration={3000}
      ContentProps={{
        "aria-describedby": "message-id"
      }}
      message={<span id="message-id">{props.error}</span>}
    />
  );
};

export default GlobalMessage;
```

To send string to that function component from another component I have these codes but, none of them are working:

```
GlobalMessage({error:"this.props.error"})
GlobalMessage.bind(null,{error:"this.props.error"})
GlobalMessage("This is an error!")
```

How to send string or data to component function ? And, I don't want to use it like this:

```
<GlobalMessage error={this.props.error} />
```

Comment: You pass down the string as a prop when you use the component, e.g. `<GlobalMessage error="This is an error!" />`

Comment: Is there any other solution to not to use that way in render?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you don't want to use the component as a component, it might fit better as a regular function.

Comment: Well, that component needs to be on top in DOM. So I put it in App.js. Now I need to send that error data to that component in App.js from another component.

Comment: You should include that in your question. You can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to set a value inside the `GlobalMessage` component in other parts of the app.

Comment: Why do you don’t want to use <GlobalMessage error={this.props.error} /> ????

Comment: Because I put that component in App.js. I don't know how to pass error data to there...

Comment: Why is this tagged "Java"?

Answer (score 0):

In React, the core of reactivity is the `state` and the `props`. Since you want to use a functional component you are down to `props`.

In my understanding, you want to send this functional component "strings" from other different components, so I guess you want to use a single component and rerender it whenever you pass it a new string. There is no simple solution to achieve this. If you want to use a single `GlobalMessage` component, using `GlobalMessage("some string")` is not the way to go, since it will create a new one on each call.

The simplest solution to achieve this that comes to my mind, without using data stores and libraries that assure reactivity like Redux or Mobx, is to somewhat adopt presentational and container components ([read more here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)).

You can create a top-level stateful class component to hold your string, lets call it `AppManager`, then display any components that you want from there.

An example of such a component:

```
class AppManager extends React.Component {
 state = {
   message: ""
 }
 setMessage = (message) => {
  this.setState({message});
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <React.Fragment>
    <App 
      setMessage={this.setMessage}
    >
    <GlobalMessage error={this.state.message} >
   </React.Fragment>
  )
 }
}
```

You can then pass the `setMessage` function along in the props to other components.
In the `App` component you can call `this.props.setMessage(message)` to send the message to `GlobalMessage`.

A more elegant and scalable solution would involve using libraries like `cartiv`, `redux` or `mobx`, but I advise you to look them up.

Hope it helps!